# Evaluate the integral $\lim_{n\to \infty} n^2 \int_0^1 (\frac{1}{1+x^2})^n dx$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, convergence-divergence

**Question.** Evaluate the following limit: $$\lim_{n\to \infty} n^2 \int_0^1 \left(\frac{1}{1+x^2}\right)^n dx$$
**My attempt**:

Let $$g(n)=n^2 \int_0^1 \left(\frac{1}{1+x^2}\right)^n dx$$

Now, clearly $g(n) > 0$  $\forall x\in [0,1]$.Now if $\dot g(n)>0$ then we can say that $g(n)$ is **strictly** increasing, hence it is divergent. (If not then it will converge to some $l\in \Bbb R$).

Therefore,
$$\begin{align}\dot g(n) &= 2n\int_0^{1}\biggr(\frac{1}{1+x^2}\biggr)^n dx +n^2\int_0^{1} \biggr(\frac{1}{1+x^2}\biggr)^n\ln\biggr(\frac{1}{1+x^2}\biggr) dx\\
&= 2n\int_0^{1}\biggr(\frac{1}{1+x^2}\biggr)^n dx -n^2\int_0^{1} \biggr(\frac{1}{1+x^2}\biggr)^n\ln(1+x^2) dx\end{align}$$

This implies $\dot g(0) =0$ and $\dot g(n) \neq 0$ for any $n \neq 0$, because there doesn't exist any $n \neq 0$ such that $n\ln(1+x^2) =2 \forall x\in\Bbb R$

Now let $\int_0^{1} \biggr(\frac{1}{1+x^2}\biggr)^n dx = F(n)$  and $\int_0^{1} \biggr(\frac{1}{1+x^2}\biggr)^n\ln(1+x^2) dx =G(n)$. Therefore we have
$$\dot g(n)=2nF(n)-n^2 G(n)$$ Now ,$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n} \biggr(\frac{1}{1+x^2}\biggr)^n =\begin{cases} 0, & \text{if }x \neq 1 \\ 1, & \text{if }x=1 \end{cases}$$
And $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{2} ln(1+x^2) \biggr(\frac{1}{1+x^2}\biggr)^n = 0$$
Hence both the limits are $\geq 0$.Therefore we can write

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n} \biggr(\frac{1}{1+x^2}\biggr)^n \geq \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{2} ln(1+x^2) \biggr(\frac{1}{1+x^2}\biggr)^n $$
$$\implies \int_0^{1} lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n} \biggr(\frac{1}{1+x^2}\biggr)^n \geq \int_0^{1}\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{2} ln(1+x^2) \biggr(\frac{1}{1+x^2}\biggr)^n$$
$$\implies \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{F(n)}{n} \geq \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{G(n)}{2}$$
$$\implies \lim_{n\to\infty} \biggr(2nF(n)-n^2G(n)\biggr) \geq 0$$ (taking n, non-negative because $n\to+\infty$).

Hence we find that $ \dot g(n) \geq 0$. Equality holds iff $n=0$.

Now when $n \to\infty$ we get $ \dot g(n) >0$.

Therefore we conclude that $g(n)$ is **strictly monotonically increasing** . Hence $$\lim_{n\to\infty} g(n) \to\infty$$
i.e.  $$\lim_{n\to \infty} n^2 \int_0^1 \biggr(\frac{1}{1+x^2}\biggr)^n dx$$ diverges. (QED)

Now my question about this is, **Is my approach correct? Is there any better or simpler approach to this?**

*P.S.* this is a question from **TIFR MATHEMATICS** . If anyone find it *duplicate* please pardon me, I am not intentionally posting duplicate questions. Thank you.

Comment: $1-\frac 1 n$ is strictly increasing but it has  a finite limit.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Ok . let me think again

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy but the derivative of $(1-\frac{1}{n})$ is converging to 0 for infinitely many n ... I.e. it's derivative is 0 for all n>k where k be any real number ... isn't it??? Plz rectify me if I'm wrong . Thank you

Answer (score 2):

A simpler approach. Note that for $x\in  [0,1],$
$$\frac{1}{1+x^2}\geq 1-x^2=(1+x)(1-x)\geq 1-x.$$
Therefore, as $n\to \infty$,
$$n^a\int_0^1 \biggr(\frac{1}{1+x^2}\biggr)^n\, dx\geq n^a\int_0^1(1-x)^n\, dx=n^a\int_0^1 x^n dx=\frac{n^a}{n+1}\to +\infty$$
as soon as $a>1$.

Comment: Ok .. so you are suggesting comparison method .. Thank you

Comment: @DebjitMullick Yes, exactly! Here, it seems to be the simplest way

Comment: now got your point.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $n^{2}\int_0^{1} (\frac 1 {1+x^{2}})^{n}dx\geq n^{2}\int_0^{1/n} (\frac 1 {1+x^{2}})^{n}dx$ and $\frac 1 {1+x^{2}} \geq \frac 1 {1+n^{-2}}$ for $0 <x<\frac  1n$. Can you now show that the limit is $\infty$?